In Android Studio, how to emulate navigation on water
Android Studio has a GPS emulator, through which you can test a navigation app. However, it only seems to work for turn-by-turn navigation, in other words, in situations in which the user follows roads or paths (typically, when driving a car). How can I simulate navigation e.g. in a forest, dessert, water, etc. where there are no roads or paths, only waypoints (to be entered by the user)?

Have you tried to build and use an gpx file as location source?
